# How to recovery the deleted Files

Tags: data-recovery

I have a Java Project (Oauth ,this is its name), and I worked on Ubuntu 12.10

And I delete it from eclipse (delete it from disk...)

This is a important Project for me .

Can anybody else tell me how can I recovery my Java Project .

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/3883/83046

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install extundelete via the software center. If that is not working you will need to recover the lost files the hard way, some call the process data carving. Basically you run a tool like foremost to search your whole disk for pattern of lost files. Have a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: The act of installing extundelete could well wipe over the files.

Comment: True, ideally you switch off the system, take a disk image and work only on that.